# Startup community website - tips on getting known

Tags: php, web, social-networking

I realise this is probably not the best place to post such as question but thought I'd try anyway. I'm developing a new community driven website in the same vein as SO. I'm just wondering the best way to get the website out there and visible.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any websites used to promote new startups and such? I'm aware of SEO techniques, etc.

The reason I'm wondering is that since it's community driven there won't be much content to get indexed by search engines.

thanks,

Jonesy

Comment: maybe you should try http://startups.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have already missed some things if you need to ask this question. The following article explains in depth on what you need to do to at least come closer to getting successful with a community site: http://jasonlbaptiste.com/featured-articles/if-you-build-it-they-wont-come/

*By the way, the whole blog is worth reading.*